# Set ImageButton state programmatically

Tags: android

I have several ImageButtons and I am trying to force one of them behave like CheckBox. When user presses the button I'd like to toggle button's background between "pressed" (orange like when you tap and hold) and "normal" states. How to to that? The code below is not really doing that.

```
    public void btnErase_click(View v) {
        ImageButton btnErase = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnErase);
        if (pressed == true)
            btnErase.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        else        
            btnErase.setBackgroundColor(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
    }
```

Comment: What is doing your code then?

Comment: Have you considered using ToggleButton and specifying its checked/unchecked appearance using XML drawables? Rather than trying to make an ImageButton behave like a ToggleButton through your own code.

Comment: I have several buttons that I want to look similar in style. Only one of them should behave differently. I will try using ToggleButton and see if its looking similar to ImageButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `View v` which is passed in, no need to find the ImageButton again. 
 
 Also, if you're setting the button background to an image use `setBackgroundResource` instead of `setBackgroundColor`

```
public void btnErase_click(View v) {
        ImageButton btnErase = (ImageButton) v;
        if (pressed == true)
            btnErase.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        else        
            btnErase.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! setBackgroundResource solved half of my problems. Now I can set set it back to the "normal" appearance.

Answer (score 2):

First, provide the selector. Save it as drawable/button_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@android:color/yellow" />
    <item drawable="@android:drawable/btn_default" />

</selector>
```

Apply it to your button as background.
In code

```
public void btnErase_click(View v) {
    ImageButton btnErase = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnErase);
    if (pressed) {
        btnErase.getBackground().setState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected});
    } else {
        btnErase.getBackground().setState(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_selected});
    }
}
```

But I don't think it's a good idea. If your button has two states better use [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) .

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setBackgroundResource` instead of `setBackgroundCOlor` in `else` clause. Because `android.R.drawable.btn_defaul` is not a color, it is id of resource.

Comment: My fault. Indeed setBackgroundResource is the right function to call.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this may be, to set different states through xml, save this in drawable and then set it as background to your button:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="#3c3c3c" />

        <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="#3399cc" />

        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:topLeftRadius="4dp" android:topRightRadius="4dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>
<item><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#171717" android:startColor="#505050" />

        <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="#3399cc" />

        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:topLeftRadius="4dp" android:topRightRadius="4dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>
```